# return function call and tertiary conditional not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a devil of a time trying to figure this out. I have a function that returns the value of another function. Within the second function I have a tertiary conditional and it will NOT get that return.. I can't figure it out. I am sure it is a scope issue, but i can't solve it. This is all within a jquery plugin.

```
 somefunctionA: function(){
   var self = this;
   var data = somecollection_of_data;
   var storeReturn = $.map( data, function( obj, i) {
                            return (function(i){
                                 return self._returnFilteredData(id);
                            })(obj.i);
             });
 },

  __returnFilteredData: function(i){
                var self = this;
                  if(some_conditionals){
                     return (
                       self.url ?
                       (function(){
                           if(some_more_conditionals){
                               self._getDBdata();  <<-- NEVER FIRES OFF
                           }
                      }) : self._getDBdata()  <<--- THIS ONE FIRES OFF
                     )
                  }
               }
            },
```

so what ends up happening is I get a "null" in the storeReturn array because in some conditionals that first tertiary fails. I cannot get into it... to test.

the "_getDBdata()" function just returns a hash based on some other data.

Any ideas on what is happening? I tried everything and I can't solve this scope/closure issue.

Comment: Where is `self` defined?  I don't see it defined in `someFunctionA`.

Comment: A function returned from a function that is used in a self executed function returned by a callback anonymous function used in `$.map`. If you cannot write (and debug) such a complex code - start with something simple that just works and make it more complex step by step.

Comment: ternary statements usually don't work very well with a bunch of function calls and if/else statements inside, they are meant for simple comparisons. Try replacing it with an if/else statement and see if that works.

Comment: @adeneo: "ternary statements usually don't work very well with a bunch of function calls" --- what do you mean by this? They **always** work very well.

Comment: @zerkms - Putting an anonymous function inside a ternary statement, and then doing more conditionals and getting something from a database inside a function that never runs and never returns anything outside the anonymous function won't work.

Comment: @adeneo: this doesn't mean ternary operator doesn't work well. It only means that programmer cannot write proper code.

Comment: That ternary statement returns either a function (inside of which is a conditional call to `self._getDBdata();`, the result of which is _not_ returned anywhere) _or_ it actually calls `self._getDBdata();` and returns its result. Surely these are not equivalent return types? Shouldn't both possible returns from the ternary be a function, or both _not_ be a function?

Comment: Obviously what is being done right now doesn't work, or else we wouldn't be looking at it. But the blanket statement that ternary statements don't work well in some situations is much too broad. Whether they should be used here is irrelevant; there is no reason this will not produce perfectly functional code.

Comment: @zerkms - Indeed, that's why this programmer should stick to if/else and console log a few thing on the way to see that it's working. It was'nt really meant as a blanket statement, but as a suggestion to the OP to try something simpler. I use ternary statements all the time, but not if I have to call an anonymous function just to do more conditionals, than I'd rather use an if/else statement and drop the anonymous function ?

Comment: The reason it is convoluted, I agree it is - is because there are soo many conditionals that must be met before I can assign data or extract it. I appreciate all your comments.

Comment: @jamesemanon—it's because of that complexity that you should keep the code simple. Get rid of the [conditional operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12) and use `if..else` as suggested. Others maintaining your code will appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: this is horribly convoluted and you should stop doing it this way. Break it out into separate pieces.

Second: you're never calling the anonymous function in that situation, you're simply returning it. Adding another set of `()` will fix that, so that you call it and return its value:

```
__returnFilteredData: function(i){
              var self = this;
                if(some_conditionals){
                   return (
                     self.url ?
                     (function(){
                         if(some_more_conditionals){
                             return self._getDBdata();
                         }
                    })() : self._getDBdata()
                   )
                }
             }
          },
```

Comment: wow dude.. i totally nubbed it up. I must be overtired.. I can't believe I didn't catch that.. wow. I see you also added the "return" in the anon function, yeah - it needed both. Thanks a bunch. I just needed some keen eyes on it. Big project and I just vegged. Thanks again. Huge help.

Answer (score 1):

In the ternary statement inside `__returnFilteredData()` you are, depending on the truthiness of `self.url`, returning one of two possible things. Whatever is returned is then returned from the callback that you provide to `$.map()`.

If `self.url` is truthy, you return a function:

```
                  (function(){
                       if(some_more_conditionals){
                           self._getDBdata();  <<-- NEVER FIRES OFF
                       }
                  })
```

...but if `self.url` is falsy, you return the result of calling a function:

```
                  self._getDBdata()
```

In the case of the anonymous function, nothing ever actually calls it, but even if something did call the anonymous function it is not actually returning a result, it conditionally calls `self._getDBdata()` without returning the result.

You could change this to an immediately invoked anonymous function that returns a result:

```
__returnFilteredData: function(i){
          var self = this;
            if(some_conditionals){
               return (
                 self.url ?
                 (function(){
                     if(some_more_conditionals){
                         return self._getDBdata();  // added "return"
                     }
                })() : self._getDBdata()            // added "()" after "})"
               )
            }
         }
      },
```

...but even then the anonymous function can still return `undefined` since it has no `else` case. Also `__returnFilteredData()` can return `undefined` if it never enters the main `if` block. Maybe `undefined` is an acceptable result for some cases, but this is far from obvious with the current code structure.

It would be *much* clearer and easier to maintain if you removed the anonymous function and the ternary and coded `__returnFilteredData()` to use an `if / else if / else if` structure.

Comment: Thank you for the succinct response... yeah, I did try to simplify it and it might be cause because I am super tired and not thinking straight,,, but if/else conditionals did not work at all. You'd think it would be a no - brainer but perhaps in my tiredness I overlooked some things. But yeah, I went to if/else first to solve it. I'll look into it later to see why it was an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment:

You are saying you can't get `if..else` to work, but I think you can't see the forest for the trees. If you get rid of the anonymous function you also get rid of `self` and the whole thing becomes very much simpler.

Note that whether `this.url` evaluates to true or false, you still call `this._getDBdata()`, so you just need to conditionally do the "some more conditionals" part:

```
__returnFilteredData: function(i) {
    if (some_conditionals) {
        if (this.url) {
            if (some_more_conditionals) {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
        return this._getDBdata();
    }
},
```

Comment: I hear what you are saying. I made it super simple. just if/else etc.. but It would not work. Literall, only an if/else. I think there is something about scope that the .map is imposing (or that particular logic). I'll try to redo very simple just to make sure, but I was going thru so many permutations and nothing was working. I might be missing something - which probably is the case.